# 2 Redux-form use 1 value, is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Hi I want to use one value in 2 redux-form components. For example it can be login. One form - login, second - forgot password. If I wrote email in login form and understood that I don't remember password, I want to go to 'i forgot' form with login, I have wrote. And then, when I accept new password, for example, I want go back to login form with the same login.

Now I try to call both forms with one name and It works but only in one direction, when I back to first form login disappear.

What I can do?

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? It's going to be hard to pin down whats going on otherwise.